# Flutter Non Consumable IAP Problems

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, flutter-in-app-purchase

With the [official plug-in](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase), I am trying to add a non-consumable IAP to my Flutter application.

However, I am experiencing some strange issues with different scenarios.

1. I can not complete the purchase when running the app on the simulator. The purchase sheet reappears after entering the sandbox user's password. PurchaseStatus never turns to complete.
2. When I run the app on a real device (iPad), I can not see my IAP on the product list. It is shown under the **notFoundIDs** list.

This new IAP was recently created and still waiting for review. I am not sure if these situations are related to approval status.

The app has already a working subscription system. I am just trying to add non-consumable IAP. I checked Aggrements if is there any pending approval but everything looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days I realized that I added a storekit configuration file that was not synced with App Store Connect. So when running on a real device it gets IAPs from that file. When I synced the configuration file my problem was solved.